# The Images on my website are becoming too narrow when reactive, any way to fix this?

Tags: css, image

the text bubble images on my webpage are becoming too narrow to read when the screen is reduced, and I cannot figure out how to make them a stable size without making them unreactive. I want users to be able to shrink the screen, but not loose the ability to see the text bubbles.If there are any suggestions/ code That I can try; I'm all ears!

```css
/* Add a background color with some padding to the body */

body {
  background: #383f51;
  font-family: Geneva, sans-serif;
  word-break: break-word;
}

/* Header and Blog Title */

header {
  background: #91c7b1;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 42px;
  font-family: "Electrolize", sans-serif;
}

header p {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 24px;
}

/* navbar/*
/* top navigation bar style */
nav {
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

/* navigation bar links */

nav a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-family: "Electrolize", sans-serif;
}

/* images and videos (work in progress at the moment) */
.avatar {
  margin: 5px;
  float: right;
  padding: 12px;
}
.bubble {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
/* Post layout for articles and aside posts */
.post {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #91c7b1;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.post h1 {
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
}

.post p {
  line-height: 2em;
  font-size: 16px;
  word-break: break-word;
}

/* Footer */

.footer {
  color: black;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #91c7b1;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>About Project Incredible Indie Games</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-about.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Electrolize&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Begin Header -->
    <header role="banner">
      <h1>Incredible Indie Games</h1>
      <p>Reviews and Reccomendations for the Moderate Indie Gamer</p>
      <!-- End Header -->
      <!-- Begin Navigation -->
    </header>
    <nav role="navigation">
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="About.html">About</a>
      <a href="Contact-form.html">Contact</a>
    </nav>
    <!-- End Navigation -->
    <!-- End Header -->
    <!-- Begin Main Content -->
    <main role="main">
      <!-- Begin Blog Posts -->
      <section class="post">
        <h1> Welcome Player Two to 'Project Incredible Indie Games' </h1>
        <img class="bubble" src="pixel-speech-bubble.png" alt="Now, you are probably asking what is project incredible games? " width="640px" height="58px">
        <p> In essence, Project Incredible Indie Games is a project dedicated to bringing more attention to lesser-known independent games by reviewing them and highlighting some of the features that I, the representative of the player, have found enjoyable. </p>
        <img class="bubble" src="pixel-speech-bubble-1.png" alt="Now, perhaps you may be wondering who I am? What makes me qualified to review games and offer recommendations?" width="1015px" height="59px">
        <figure class="avatar">
          <img src="Cute-avatar.png" alt="Picrew Avatar of my beautiful face" height="250px" width="250px">
          <figcaption>Artistic picture of Me, Abby Lake</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <p> My name is Abby Lake, and I have years of experience with various gaming systems, including: NES (Nintendo Entertainment System); Nintendo Gamecube; Nintendo DS, DSI, 3DS; Nintendo Wii; PlayStation; PS2; PS3; PS4; WiiU; Nintendo Switch; as well as Personal Computer.</p>
        <p> While I by no means claim to be an expert, I have enough experience to provide an honest review of games that will be understood and hopefully appreciated by moderate to casual players </p>
        <p> Please feel free to join me on this quest to share some 'hidden gems' of the Indie game world by visiting this blog often or recommending a game I should review and/or recommend.</p>
      </section>
      <!-- End Blog Posts -->
    </main>
    <!--End Main -->
    <!--Begin Footer-->
    <footer class="footer" role="contentinfo">
      <p>Blog Created by: Abby Lake</p>
    </footer>
    <!--End Footer-->
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: 'the text bubble images on my webpage are becoming too narrow to read when the screen is reduced' could you explain a little bit more? I shrink my screen and text is fully readable. I see there are some pictures but they can't load maybe that's the case. To load pictures you can use lorem picsum for eg https://picsum.photos/200/300

Comment: The images themselves are good lengthwise, but can be hard to read because they are narrow height wise when the screen becomes smaller left to right. Hope that clarifies things!